# Flyoutpage in NavigationPage not working on Android?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I've been trying to port my Xamarin app to Maui, but I'm stuck at the navigation part. Whenever I try to wrap my flyoutpage in a navigation page

```
     MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AppFlyout());
```

On Android, the menu icon disappears and navigation is messed up. I can enter the flyout menu by swiping and from there navigate to another page, but when I then press the 'back' button the main page is just blank, but code is executed.

I started a new project just adding the flyout menu, but the same problem arises.

[missing menu icon top left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDjC3.png)

[flyout open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7St8t.png)

[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBRzs.png)

[blank mainpage after navigating back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7yLX.png)

If I just do:

```
     MainPage = new AppFlyout();
```

Then the menu icon is visible but of course navigation.pushAsync is not working. Here's my code:

```
    <FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
            x:Class="TestApp.AppFlyout"
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" 
            NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
            FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover">
        <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
            <local:FlyoutMenuPage x:Name="flyoutPage" />
        </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <FlyoutPage.Detail>
            <NavigationPage>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <local:MainPage />
                </x:Arguments>
            </NavigationPage>
        </FlyoutPage.Detail>
    </FlyoutPage>
```

```
    public partial class AppFlyout : FlyoutPage
    {

        public AppFlyout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            flyoutPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItemIndex >= 0)
            {
                switch (e.SelectedItemIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
                        break;
                }

                flyoutPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.FlyoutMenuPage"
             Title="Menu">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="BlueViolet">
                <Label Text="TestApp" TextColor="yellow" Margin="10,20,0,0"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public" BackgroundColor="White">
                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                    <MenuItemCollection>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="Page2MenuItem" Text="Page2"/>
                    </MenuItemCollection>
                </ListView.ItemsSource>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="5,10" BackgroundColor="White">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconImageSource}" WidthRequest="40"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="Black"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

```
    public partial class FlyoutMenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        public FlyoutMenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage( new AppFlyout());
        }
    }
```

On iOS, everything is working as expected. It's just Android where it's not working (no hamburger and blank screen). On Xamarin, it worked on both iOS and Android. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project with your code and reproduced the problem. In addition, I found that this problem also appeared on the windows platform.

When I debug the project, the Page2's constructor has been triggered but the page didn't render on the android and windows. It appears a bug and you can report this on the repo.

Finally, I found a workaround that make the `PushAsync(new Page2())` render successfully when you used the `MainPage = new AppFlyout();` You can make the AppFlyout's Details page be the NavigationStack's root:

```
switch (e.SelectedItemIndex)
{
   case 0:
       await this.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
       break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, workaround is working as expected. I will report this.